# How to remove event listeners in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

How to remove event listeners in Aurelia?

This doesn’t appear to do anything:

```
detached(){
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.windowScroll);
}
```

The event is still firing when i change routes.

I am attaching it in the `constructor()` in my view-model file:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.windowScroll.bind(this));
```

I also tried `deactivate()` and neither are firing when I change routes.

Comment: `bind` returns a new function... try to change your attaching code to `this.windowScroll = this.windowScroll.bind(this); window.addEventListener('scroll', this.windowScroll);` then the `detached` event should remove the subscription

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least one, but maybe two issues here.

### Setting up an event listener

If you can't use the Aurelia binding for event delegation (for which scroll may or may not be a case, I haven't tried it), then you should use the attached lifecycle callback to set up your event handlers, **not** the constructor. The reason being that, unless you specify your view model is transient, the constructor will be called **once**. Instead, you really want Aurelia to turn on your event handlers every time it is attached.

```
attached = () => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}
```

### How to write a lifecycle callback

In general you should write your lifecycle callbacks using the arrow notation. This is because, IIRC, your `this` may get reassigned during the activation lifecycle. The arrow notation in TypeScript/ES6 will preserve your `this` lexically, i.e., it is what you expect it to be.

```
detached = () => { 
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that you need to define your bindable function up in the constructor if you want to unbind it again on detach:

```
export MyClass {

constructor() {

    this.handleBodyClick = e => {

        console.log(e.target);
    };
}

attached() {

    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleBodyClick);
}

detached() {

    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleBodyClick);
}
```

Taken directly from this excellent post: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-event-listeners-in-aurelia/